# Enable tab auto-completion case-insensitive in GHCI

Tags: haskell, terminal, ghci

It's bothersome for me to have to press `shift` key whenever to type `Main.hs` in `ghci`.

```
> :l Main.hs
```

Is there a way to make `ghci` tab completion case-insensitive? I couldn't find a fieldname in `~/.haskeline` for this.

Comment: You know you can just do `:r` after you've loaded it once, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response. `x <- readFile "Main.png"` for example, is another case for this.

Comment: I really doubt this is a feature very many people would care for, so wouldn't be surprised if it was never implemented. But if you do... can't be too difficult, just write a suitable [`CompletionFunc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.4.0/docs/System-Console-Haskeline-Completion.html#v:completeFilename).